# JSON.Net Serialize list with root name

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I've looked and can't find anything and this is really starting to annoy me...

I've got JSON.Net and the following snippet of code

```
var x = insList.Select(a => new
{
    ac = a.CreatedDate,
    bd = a.CreatedBy
 });
 this.Context.Response.Write(x.ToJSON());
```

.ToJSON() is a simple extension method:

```
public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
    { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); }
```

The json output is

[image]

Ideally what I'd like is the highlight bits to have the same root name, rather than just {}

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects do not have names in JSON, properties do.  (See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).)  Therefore, if you want to name an object, you'll have to make it the value of a property of another containing object.

```
var x = insList.Select(a => new
{
    rootName = new 
    {
        ac = a.CreatedDate,
        bd = a.CreatedBy
    }
});
```

This will yield the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "rootName": {
      "ac": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "bd": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "rootName": {
      "ac": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "bd": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "rootName": {
      "ac": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "bd": 0
    }
  }
]
```